# How do I create a dictionary out of each user with their current game? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I thought of somethinh like this:

```
var userGames = {};
for (i=0; i< client.getListOfOnlineUsers(); i++) {
   var key = client.getListOfOnlineUsers()[i];
   userGames.key = client.getListOfOnlineUsers()[i].presence.game;
}
```

Is this the right way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used `discordjs`, so correct me if I got anything wrong. As I understand it, `getListOfOnlineUsers` returns the array of users and `user.presence.game` will give you the game. If so, you have the correct idea, just a minor correction on line 4:

```
var userGames = {};
for (i=0; i< client.getListOfOnlineUsers(); i++) {
   var key = client.getListOfOnlineUsers()[i];
   userGames[key] = client.getListOfOnlineUsers()[i].presence.game;
}
```

This should work for you. The `[key]` is used here because `key` is a variable and the real value of the dictionary key is computed at run-time.

Also, you should probably avoid calling the same function over and over when it returns the same result. Save the data in a variable. Maybe, use `forEach` and `let` too.

```
let userGames = {};
const userList = client.getListOfOnlineUsers();
userList.forEach(u => userGames[u] = u.presence.game);
```

Looks a lot cleaner imo.

Comment: Okay thank you! A reminder for everyone reading this: `client.getListOfOnlineUsers()` is not a real function. I just used it to represent the problem.